# syntax and database connection error in node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Below is my database coonnection code in node.

```
var express = require('express')
var mongoose = require('mongoose') 
var cors = require('cors') 

var morgan = require('morgan')
require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()

 //db
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useFindAndModify:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:false,
    useCreateIndex:true,
 })
  .then(() => console.log('DB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log('DB Connection Error =>', err))

   //middleware
app.use(express.json({limit:'5mb'}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:'true'}))
app.use(cors({
    origin:["http://localhost:3000"]
}))

app.post("/api/register", (req, res) =>{
    console.log("Register Endpoint =>", req.body);
})

const port = process.env.PORT
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`))
```

when I run this code I get errors :

1. C:\Users\atiqu\merncamp\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:70
   pkFactory: db.options?.pkFactory ?? utils_1.DEFAULT_PK_FACTORY,
   ^
2. SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
   at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1300:10)

I was trying to connect my database and these errors arised.

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: If there is a complete stack trace it should be included (as formatted text) as well, preferably with an indication of where in **your** code there's a syntax error. If the syntax error is not in **your** code then it may be a packaging issue, which is a different thing altogether.

Comment: How can I solve this problem? I have posted my code as formatted text. @DaveNewton

Comment: The entire stack trace should be included as formatted text. If the syntax error is in **your** code it's helpful to be specific with where in your code the error is. If the syntax error is not in **your** code  then it may be a packaging issue which means we need to see how the app is being packaged.

Comment: Since one of the errors explicitly points to a node module it might be useful to include the version of Node you're running as well.

Comment: v19.5.0. and I dont understand how to include the entire stack.

Comment: When you run the code there's errors: that's the stack trace. Cut and paste it into a code block in the question.

Comment: SO, the entire stack is too long. I am leaving some :- C:\Users\atiqu\merncamp\server>npm start

> server@1.0.0 start
> nodemon -r esm server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.21
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node -r esm server.js`
C:\Users\atiqu\merncamp\server\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1

Comment: The stack trace should be a formatted block in the question.

Comment: then a huge stack of 299007 characters and then the two errors mentioned in my question

Comment: A 300k stack trace. That seems unlikely for a syntax error. In any case if the syntax error is not in your code then I would expect a packaging error which means we need to see how the app is being packaged. I really feel like I'm repeating myself a lot.

Comment: How can I show you how my app is being packaged? I apologize for my little learning and thank you so much as you are giving me the time.

Comment: @atiquezaman what is the value off `process.env.DATABASE`? is it only `database name` or a `connection string`?

Comment: its a connection string that I put in a .env file. @TobokSitanggang

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. I downgraded my `mongoose` from v7 to v6.
in `package.json` file I changed `"mongoose": "^7.0.1",` to  `"mongoose": "^6.7.3",` then run `npm install` and I was able to connect to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using this:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
  useNewUrlParser:true,
  useFindAndModify:true,
  useUnifiedTopology:false,
  useCreateIndex:true,
})
```

Please use:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue,

1. I downgraded mongoose to 6.9.2 in package.json file.
2. I reinstalled mongoose
   npm install mongoose

It staerted working after that :) hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue like yours

```
pkFactory: db.options?.pkFactory ?? utils_1.DEFAULT_PK_FACTORY,
```

[image: nodemon version issue]

I just downgraded my mongoose version to v`6.7.3` & my problem is solved.
In my case the current stable version is v`7.4.3`, There are some errors in this version.
Just uninstall the current version like `yarn remove mongoose` or `npm uninstall mongoose` and install v`6.7.3` like `yarn add mongoose@6.7.3` or `npm i mongoose@6.7.3`.