# "Invalid or unexpected token" error when importing mongoose 7.3.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose to connect to a mongodb atlas cluster. When I run my app, I get the following error, after a long string of garbage output.

```
/path/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:74
            pkFactory: db.options?.pkFactory ?? utils_1.DEFAULT_PK_FACTORY,
                                  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
```

I've found the root cause to be: `import mongoose from 'mongoose'`. My code runs without it, but once I import I get this error. I don't even use mongoose anywhere else in the code yet.

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675925/syntax-and-database-connection-error-in-node-js) which covers the same question, but the only working solution is to downgrade mongoose to version 6.7.3.

I determined the change from mongoose 6.x to 7.x breaks my code. Furthermore, I think the actual break is from mongodb 4.x to 5.x. I looked into the notes for that change but I'm not sure how I could be importing it wrong. My node version is 16.17.0, npm version 8.15.0, and the mongodb version that gets installed is 5.6.0. My text encoding is utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have cracked it! My start script was `node -r esm app.js`, which is supposed to allow local runs for ECMAScript modules. There seems to be some compatibility issue with this for later versions of mongodb.

To solve:

First, remove the `-r esm` from your start command. Next, either:

1. Change your `.js` extensions to `.mjs` (difference explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492546/what-is-the-difference-between-js-and-mjs-files))
2. Add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`

Both should have the same effect.