# I am Having a problem with mongoose package. after installing the when i run my app it shows the following message

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm, mongoose

### I am unable to run my application because of this issue.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbSt5.png) <- image for reference

### I have installed the mongoose npm package to connect with the mongodb but after installing the mongoose package  and running the app it's throwing the error like

B:\angular\online\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:74
pkFactory: db.options?.pkFactory ?? utils_1.DEFAULT_PK_FACTORY,
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)

### And my application get crashed..

Comment: I get results when searching that message on this site (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675925/syntax-and-database-connection-error-in-node-js))

Comment: thank you. well i got this fix by down grading the mongoose version to 6.x.x something. if this issue resolve in the lastest version then i will let you guys know.